# Simplify fraction in numerator when fraction is part of sum

Tags: fractions

I have the result of a quotient rule:

$$
\frac{\frac{x}{8+x}-ln8}{x^2}
$$

Should I just leave it? Would it be appropriate to separate the fraction into a product of fractions with denominator $x^2$, simplify the left side, and give the result as a product of two fractions?

Any soln using addition or subtraction of fractions is unacceptable and messier than just leaving as is.

Comment: It's worth learning how to simplify this. But if you get an exam question on the quotient rule and you're not told to simplify what you get, leave it. No chance to introduce an error, and easier for the instructor to grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplification is often in the eye of the beholder.  I think most people dislike compound fractions, so I would take this to $$\frac 1{x(8+x)}-\frac {\ln 8}{x^2}$$
Whether you expand the first denominator is a matter of taste.  You might also put the two fractions over a common denominator.  Take your pick.

Comment: Would you please show the legal steps for producing this?

Comment: It is separating the fractions into a sum (or difference, not product) of fractions with denominator $x^2$  The first part just goes $\dfrac {\frac x{8+x}}{x^2}=\frac x{x^2(8+x)}=\frac1{x(8+x)}$